# Multithreading with Watchdog

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, watchdog, python-watchdog

I need to run a function on all new files in a folder.

I've chosen watchdog to detect event handling, as it is rather straightforward to use. However, as the operation on each file takes roughly 30-40 seconds, the process takes relatively long whenever large quantities (ex 1000 files) of files have been added to the folder.

I have heard of multi threading, and I believe that this is the answer to my issue: Instead of running the function one by one on each item that is added - running the function (do_smth) on as many files as possible, given the restriction of my RAM. How should I go about it?

Please a minimal reproducable example of my code below:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


folder_to_watch= "/trigger_folder"


class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def do_smth(self):
        print("do_something")
        time.sleep(2)
    def on_created(self, event): # when file is created
        print("Got event for file %s" % event.src_path)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.do_smth()

observer = Observer()
event_handler = EventHandler() # create event handler
# set observer to use created handler in directory
observer.schedule(event_handler, path=folder_to_watch)
observer.start()

# sleep until keyboard interrupt, then stop + rejoin the observer
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Edit 1:
The do_stmh function in reality checks if the new file is an image file, and if so opens it via cv2, takes its height and width, and saves it to a .csv file among some other operations (that unfortunately take longer).

Comment: Are the operations you run on those files CPU or I/O bound? If it's the latter, multithreading won't help you much because all threads/processes will have to wait for the non-parallel disk.

Comment: Good point! Its CPU bound if I'm not mistaken. I'm basically opening the image files, taking some information from them, and saving it to a .csv file. Thus, multithreading should help, correct? (Only issue this brings is that I can't open an already opened .csv file, but this seems not too important for the sake of the question asked)